# viewing sql query on a form

Tags: sql, ms-access

using ms-access 2013, I've written a query that has a lot of variables in it. Is there a way to see the query as it was run, with the variable names replaced by the value of the variable?
Instead of "Select * where name = strName..." I'm looking for it as it was run, "Select * where name = "jones" for example. Is there a way to display it on a form (where the query is in a subform)?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can. Look into `DoCmd.ApplyFilter()` or change sql in `Form.RecordSource = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:
1. Do this in VBA. When you construct the SQL query (adding filters in VBA), you use the resulting SQL twice: once to execute as a SQL query, once to place as text in a textbox control.
2. If your filters on the query are on forms, you can update a textbox control that constructs your SQL. So if your input is a control named **txt_LastName**, in the **txt_SQL** textbox where you want to show the complete SQL, the **Control Source** would be:

```
="Select * where name = " & Chr(34) & [txt_LastName] & Chr(34)
```

When **txt_LastName** is set to **Jones** then **txt_SQL** would be set to:
**Select * where name = "Jones"**